# Manipulating table cell size and width on different viewports using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to basically have a table in my design where the size varies from **3 X 3** to **7 X 7** and need the full table to fit the small screens too.

So now going deeper, when the screen size is that of a **mobile device** I want the **table to stretch full width**, while **on larger screens** I need them to be in the **center of the screen**. Along with that in any screen size, the cells dimensions should be **width = height**, in other words a square.

How can I do this with CSS and TWITTER-BOOTSTRAP only?

**P.S:** I am new to bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></span> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td data-cell="0"></td>
                <td data-cell="1"></td>
                <td data-cell="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-cell="3"></td>
                <td data-cell="4"></td>
                <td data-cell="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-cell="6"></td>
                <td data-cell="7"></td>
                <td data-cell="8"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.site-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-top: 5px solid #5A332B;
    background-color: #ccbb99 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Just couldn't do the pure css version and powered with jQuery:

```js
function setHeight() {
  var myTable = $("#myTable");
  myTable.height(myTable.width());
     $( window ).resize(function() {
         myTable.height(myTable.width());
     });
}

setHeight();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.site-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-top: 5px solid #5A332B;
    background-color: #ccbb99 !important;
}

.container {
    
  }
.table {
  width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 5%;
} 

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .table {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></span> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<div class="container">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td data-cell="0">0</td>
                <td data-cell="1">1</td>
                <td data-cell="2">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-cell="3">3</td>
                <td data-cell="4">4</td>
                <td data-cell="5">5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-cell="6">6</td>
                <td data-cell="7">7</td>
                <td data-cell="8">8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On larger screen it sticks to the left.

Comment: Click run code snippet and then Full page button at the right

Comment: My mistake, I should have put in some more html and css in the question. Now updated. But somehow the table isnt centered properly.

Comment: Still working, please check again updated, just added my css rules right after yours

Comment: At somepoint, the table cell stretches. Actually am trying to make a tic tac toe game, so hopefully now you can understand how I want the table to adapt on different devices.

Comment: Can you please check again?

Comment: Squeezes too much on small screen

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue then you should change `table` structure to `div`. Because you need **square** box for every device screen size. Also you need to write little bit of `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.

```js
$(function(){
  var newBoxHeight= $('#square-box .col-xs-4').outerWidth();
  $('#square-box .col-xs-4').outerHeight(newBoxHeight);
});
```

```css
.col-xs-4{
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.col-xs-4:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color: #020202;
}
.col-xs-4:nth-child(2n+2){
  background-color: #121212;
}
.center-content{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.table-box,
.tbale-cell-box{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
.table-box{
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
.tbale-cell-box{
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="square-box">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">1</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">2</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">3</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">4</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">5</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">6</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">7</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">8</span></span></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="center-content"><span class="table-box"><span class="tbale-cell-box">9</span></span></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I did the above changes, but when the screen sizes becomes short, the cells become vertical rectangles.

Comment: Refresh page when change the screen resolution. or You need to use  `resize` event for responsive layout. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: cant it be simply done with tables? Then it will be easier to generate random table with different grid sizes?

Comment: if we use rows, what if a person wants to have a 7 X 7 grid?